# How can I detect case sensitive word in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I detect case sensitive word in regex?
Language: JavaScript

- That is, if I am looking for `SO`
- It will trigger for only `SO`
- but not for `so` or `So` or `sO`

Comment: Just `SO` should work. Regex is already case sensitive.

Comment: Isn't working for me in a website. I'm refreshing automatically and trying to catch a word. But it's catching all the case insensitive words.

Comment: How are you doing the regexp search?

Comment: This site is about programming, what programming language are you using?

Comment: Sorry. It's an website and they are using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

add 'i' modifier that means "ignore case"
new RegExp('^' + string + '$', "i")